# Banner Width not working

Tags: width, banner

I am trying to adjust my banner for my website. It is coming out very small and Im not sure where to update the details of this banner so it displays at the proper size of 960 pixels in width.

My website http://www.elisheamoore.truevisionwebdesigns.com/

and my account with Jssor is https://jssor.com/taureaavant!

Answer (score 0):

Jssor Slider will always scale by default while window resizing.
Please modify the 'Responsive' options.

http://www.jssor.com/slider-maker/keep-slider-responsive.html